# I am using sql statement with select id=@@identity set nocount off but i get ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g, when I executing the following query I got error like (ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended)

this query works fine at sql server but in oracle it gives error

```
insert into tbl_scheduler(startdat,enddat,sdat,endt) 
values ('Sun, 06 Jan 2013 15:45:00 GMT', 'Sun, 06 Jan 2013 16:07:00 GMT','06-Jan-13','06-Jan-13') 
select id=@@identity 
set nocount off
```

error occurred when I add  "select id=@@identity set nocount off" to the query

Comment: That looks like SQL Server syntax, `@@` isn't part of the grammar in Oracle. What is `identity` supposed to mean?

Comment: That **will not** work in oracle, that is SQL-server specific syntax. Oracle does not have autoincrement columns, but instead uses sequences and triggers to automatically fill a field.

Comment: Additionally: Oracle requires statements to be terminated with a `;` (which you should get used to in SQL Server as well...)

Answer (score -3):

may be you can using delimiter ;

```
insert into tbl_scheduler(startdat,enddat,sdat,endt) values('Sun, 06 Jan 2013 15:45:00 GMT', 'Sun, 06 Jan 2013 16:07:00 GMT','06-Jan-13','06-Jan-13');
select id=@@identity;
set nocount off;
```